# SetTimeout function with parameter and without Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback

I confused what the **differences** between these 2 options and if there is a better one
the parameter in the timeout function is outside

```
function createPost(){
  setTimeout(function(post){
    posts.push(post);
  }, 2000);
}
```

at another function parameter inside createPost function

```
function createPost(post){
  setTimeout(function(){
    posts.push(post);
  }, 2000);
}
```

**Solution:**

there are 2 different things and only the 2nd option will work

Comment: The first will give you an error unless you pass an array as a third argument to setTimeout

Comment: Related: [Global variable is logged as undefined when passed as parameter to setTimeout callback function](/q/32326721/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimout's first parameter is a callback function that will be executed after the timeout. It simply calls the function. It doesn't pass any parameters to it.

The second option is the only one that will work. You'll call createPost(post) and it will push to the array after the timeout that post.

Comment: thanks  and sorry about the not good question I am just a beginner

Comment: Thats ok, I'm not one of those who downvoted the question. But you should do more research before asking here, you could have tried to execute it and see that only the second one works.